# find unique list in a list contains many dicts python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm struggling to find the unique list of dicts inside a list:

```
d = [[{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':1, 'y':2}], [{'x':3, 'y':4}, {'x':3, 'y':4}], [{'x':1, 'y':2}, {'x':1, 'y':2}]]
```

It should return:

```
results = d = [[{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':1, 'y':2}], , [{'x':3, 'y':4}, {'x':3, 'y':4}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a trick, but you can try using `json.dumps` and `json.loads`:

```
import json

d = set(json.dumps(i) for i in d)
d = [json.loads(i) for i in d]
```

Output:

```
[[{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}], [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}]]
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that this depends on key order of the dicts, which may or may not be important.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using below

```
[list(map(dict,k)) for k in set(tuple(tuple(j.items()) for j in i) for i in d)]
#[[{'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}], [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}]]
```